# Laravel button, onclick function without change URL

Tags: php, laravel, button, routes, laravel-blade

I need create button in blade without any change of URL, im totaly lost, dont know what im doing wrong.

When i press the button, my url is changed how route is set. What is correct way to set buttons in Laravel?

This is my try:

```
public function sendMessageButton()
{
    $phoneNumber = 123456789;
    $phoneMessage = 'Hi';

    return SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber, $phoneMessage);
}
```

`sendMessageButton` is very simple function, `SendTextMessage` is custom class with connection to GSM gateway.

`blade`

```
<button type="button" id="sendText" name="sendText" onclick="window.location='{{ route('sendSms') }}'">
```

I found on internet, that i need set `Route` to controller.

```
Route::get('/','SendController@sendMessageButton')->name('sendSms');
```

And there is my problem, `''` this part of route, changing my URL, how can i avoid this ? i just need, press the button and get return `SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber, $phoneMessage);` and stay on my URL where im.

Comment: Your route URI method is wrong, you cant use a empty URI. At least you need to define a **/**

Comment: you need to use javascript for that, handle the onclick event by sending an ajax request to an endpoint that sends the message.

Comment: try adding a redirect with action to the controller back to index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cinameng nice tip

`route`

```
Route::get('/send','SendController@sendMessageButton')->name('sendSms');
```

`controller`

change this

```
return SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber, $phoneMessage);
```

to

```
SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber, $smsCode, $smsExpirationTime);

return back();
```